# Jenkins: Cloud or AMI instance cap would be exceeded for: <name>

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

Using the `ec2` plugin v1.39 to start worker nodes on EC2, I am faced with this error (and huge stack trace) every time I start a new node.

```
Cloud or AMI instance cap would be exceeded for: <name>
```

I have set the (previously unset) `Instance Cap` to 10 in both fields in Configure System. This did not fix it.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem? Thanks

EDIT 1:

I have tried changing the instance size, with no change (I went M3Medium -> M4Large).

See [full stack trace here](https://gist.github.com/mafrosis/72fbe6bf93dba9fefd342011e85ec215).

I can also launch an `m4.large` from the console. Turns out the `m3.medium` doesn't exist in Sydney.. Hmm

Comment: Can you paste some of the stack trace?have you also tried to launch the slave manually and see if that works fine?

Comment: Are you using the same role/instance profile with the same role (console Vs Jenkins)?also double check the number of executors per slave, just in case

Comment: have you tried to enable debug logging?

Comment: I am noob. I can see a stack trace showing my error in /log/all. Add an answer saying this and I will give you points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting all the log levels to ALL might give you extra information about the error, endpoint in /log/levels

Anyway it seems like an issue we had previously with the private ssh key not set properly, therefore the slave can't be connected and keeps increasing the cap.

Comment: You are correct. The info I needed was in /log/all the whole time :'(